# I`m creating a calendar-app using django. Calendar must be vertical

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, calendar

For now I have realized this [django-calendar](https://www.huiwenteo.com/normal/2018/07/29/django-calendar-ii.html) . But i need [vertical calendar](http://3mu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/calendar-2019-ver-dni.png)(sorry, haven`t found any in English) On the left we have weekday headers and month names on the top.

I started overriding [python-calendar](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/calendar.py) HTMLCalendar methods. I thought to write new formatweekdayrow method, which would generate row of mondays, tuesdays .... sundays. But i got stuck as i dont fully understand how these all methods work.

So the question is should i think over my idea of writing formatweekdayrow, or is it not possible to make vertical calendar like that? Or may be there is some simple and smarter way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote several methods and got what I need

```
class Vertical(HTMLCalendar):

    def formatweekrow(self, theweeks, daynum):
        """
        Return a complete week as a table row.
        """
        v = []
        s = v.append
        s('<tr>')
        for theweek in theweeks:
            for (d, wd) in theweek:
                if wd == daynum:
                    s(self.formatday(d, wd))
        s('</tr>')
        return ''.join(v)

    def formatmonth(self, theyear, themonth, withyear=True):
        """
        Return a formatted month as a table.
        """
        cnt = 0
        v = []
        theweeks = self.monthdays2calendar(theyear, themonth)
        a = v.append
        a('<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"     class="">')
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatmonthname(theyear, themonth, withyear=withyear))
        a('\n')
        a(self.formatweekheader())
        a('\n')
        while cnt < 7:
            a(self.formatweekrow(theweeks, cnt))
            a('\n')
            cnt += 1
        a('</table>')
        a('\n')
        return ''.join(v)
```